# mail chimp popup signup form

Tags: integration, mailchimp

I have code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us9.list-manage.com","uuid":"70c1688f7bd048571a0d7d50c","lid":"1d7852db3d"}) })</script>
```

I want to put it in my html website. I tried pasting this code in header but nothing happen.

How to add this code in the website?